# Is there a performance difference between INT and NUMERIC as primary key in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, primary-key

Is there a measurable performance difference between using INT vs. NUMERIC as a primary key in `T-SQL` (MS SQL Server)?

I need to increase the performance of SQL selects and updates for the existing database whose tables use the NUMERIC as primary keys. For example:

```
[ID] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

`SELECT ID FROM table`

will give us: 1, 2, 3 ... etc

I assume that using INT would be preferable. But will there be a performance improvement?

Comment: Try both and *measure it*. Only you will know what query patterns, data volumes, secondary indexes, etc you're going to have in your database.

Comment: Why not try to resolve the performance issue you have with your existing query first ? I doubt changing from `numeric` to `int` will give you several fold of increase in performance

Comment: In general I tend to say: INT will be better (due to bus width and count of step a comparisson will need). But if this is *measurable*? Eric Lippert wrote a [good article on this: Race your horses!](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Changing `numeric` to `int` is one of the several directions to increase performance

Comment: @AleksBro not really - the *size* may or may not be different. After all `[numeric](18, 0)` requires a bigint, not an int. I seriously doubt you'll be able to *measure* any performance differences. *Real* differences come from writing good queries, having the correct indexes, having fast storage and lots of RAM

Comment: @AleksBro you'll get better performance by using *compression* - that reduces both the storage size and IO. IO is the biggest performance killer in a database.

Comment: @AleksBro what is your *actual* performance problem? Integers, whether bigint or int or tinyint are better semantically, not for any big performance benefit. You'd see a storage difference in a big fact table (millions of rows * 1 byte for bigints), but then, using a *columnstore* index would improve performance by orders of magnitue, by using columnar storage and data compression

Answer (score 0):

Well, regarding storage, [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is on 4 bytes while [`numeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is on 5 byte with precision between 1 and 5 and 9 bytes with precision between 9 bytes, so from this point of view, `int` has better performance.

Comment: Takes less space, yes. Better performance - I doubt one could measure it

Comment: Of course it's better performance: less bytes read from disk/memory and then sent over the network.

Comment: I agree.  It probably has increased performance but it is probably so small you would never realize it in actual use.  Use the one that is going to make more sense down the road.

Comment: That would matter in a bulk export operation. In almost every case though, the difference will be negligible compared to indexes, well written queries, etc. As for "less bytes", it's just 1. Tthe equivalent to a `decimal(18,0)` is `bigint` which takes 8 bytes

Comment: You are right regarding better performance gained from indexes, well written queries and others, but the question was if int is better than numeric for a PK. Event if it is just a small improvement, int is better. I think it's time now to get back to indexes so we can see actually an improvement than debating something that small.